# date vector input for dyEvents in dygraphs: R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I have vector of dates which can be chosen from a drop-down box where  **multiple dates can be chosen**. By selecting those dates event lines will appear at the dates which has been chosen. However I see that the dyEvent is not taking a vector of dates.When date in dyEvent is replaced by a vector event lines do not appear. I have provided the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ui.R
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tool"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("choosedates")
      ),
    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("plot")
      )
  )
  ))


server.R
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  Data<-data.frame(Time=seq(as.Date("7/29/2012","%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date("8/7/2012","%m/%d/%Y"),by="1 day"),Volume=c(100,150,120,300,250,50,100,120,80,100))
  output$choosedates<-renderUI({
    selectInput("dates","Choose dates to be marked by event line",as.character(Data$Time),multiple=TRUE)
  })
  library(xts)
  Dataxts<-reactive({
    xts(Data$Volume,order.by=as.Date(Data$Time,"%m/%d/%Y"))
  })
  output$plot<-renderDygraph({
    dygraph(Dataxts(), main = "Visualization")%>%
      dyEvent(date =as.character(input$dates), "Dummy", labelLoc = "bottom",color = "red", strokePattern = "dashed")%>%
      dyAxis("y", label = "Units sold in millions")%>%
      dyOptions(axisLabelColor = "Black",digitsAfterDecimal = 2,drawGrid = FALSE)
  })
  })
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is that your are trying to pipe the result of `dyEvent(...)` forward while you are still in the body of your `for` loop. It will be much easier to help you if you provide enough additional code and data to run your application.

Comment: @nrussell  I have modified my approach a bit and uploaded a similar code.

Comment: I think it's a better way, at least shorter:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32837723/6253668

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have any prior experience with the package `dygraphs` so I can't guarantee this is the simplest approach, but I was able to get the application to function correctly with the code below.

---

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
##
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Tool"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("choosedates")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("plot")
    )
  )
))
```

---

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
##
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  Data <- data.frame(
    Time=seq(as.Date("7/29/2012","%m/%d/%Y"),
             as.Date("8/7/2012","%m/%d/%Y"),
             by="1 day"),
    Volume=c(100,150,120,300,250,
             50,100,120,80,100))

  output$choosedates <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "dates",
      "Choose dates to be marked by event line",
      as.character(Data$Time),
      multiple=TRUE)
  })

  Dataxts <- reactive({
    xts(
      Data$Volume,
      order.by=as.Date(Data$Time,"%m/%d/%Y"))
  })
  ##
  getDates <- reactive({
    as.character(input$dates)
  })

  addEvent <- function(x,y) {
    dyEvent(
      dygraph=x,
      date=y,
      "Dummy", 
      labelLoc = "bottom",
      color = "red", 
      strokePattern = "dashed")
  }

  basePlot <- reactive({ 
    if (length(getDates()) < 1) {
      dygraph(
        Dataxts(),
        main="Visualization") %>%
        dyAxis(
          "y", 
          label = "Units sold in millions") %>%
        dyOptions(
          axisLabelColor = "Black",
          digitsAfterDecimal = 2,
          drawGrid = FALSE)
    } else {
      dygraph(
        Dataxts(),
        main="Visualization") %>%
        dyAxis(
          "y", 
          label = "Units sold in millions") %>%
        dyOptions(
          axisLabelColor = "Black",
          digitsAfterDecimal = 2,
          drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
        dyEvent(
          dygraph=.,
          date=getDates()[1],
          "Dummy", 
          labelLoc = "bottom",
          color = "red", 
          strokePattern = "dashed")
    }
  })
  ##
  output$plot <- renderDygraph({

    res <- basePlot()
    more_dates <- getDates()
    if (length(more_dates) < 2) {
      res
    } else {
      Reduce(function(i,z){
        i %>% addEvent(x=.,y=z)
      }, more_dates[-1], init=res)
    }

  })

})
```

---

The major changes are the functions between the two commented lines (`##`). I made a reactive function `getDates()` that just returns the current selection of dates - I'm not even sure if this is necessary but this is generally what I do with user input. More importantly, I created a (non-reactive) function `addEvent` that was purposely defined in such a way that is convenient to use with the higher-order function `Reduce` - i.e. the `x` argument represents the previous state (the `dygraph` object being accumulated), and the `y` argument is the modification we make to the previous state (the line we are adding).

`basePlot()` is mostly just a helper function to avoid errors that would most likely be produced when the application first starts (and no date input is selected). If no dates are chosen, it outputs the base `dygraph`, and if one or more are chosen, it outputs the base graph plus *only the first* date line.

To return a final plot object (in `output$plot`), we create the base plot (`res`), and check for the existence of multiple date inputs. If two or more lines are requested by the user, we use `Reduce` and the UDF `addEvent` to accumulate modifications (date lines), using `res` as the initial value, and the 2nd through last date inputs as the modifying values.

---

Here are a few screen shots of the running applications:

**Startup:** 
[image]

---

**First input:** 
[image]

---

**Multiple inputs:** 
[image]

Comment: That was brilliant! The best answer I have ever received. Thank you @nrussell. You were of great help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a better solution, at least, shorter:

```
p <- dygraph(df_sub)
for (i in 1:dim(df_sub)[1]){
p <- p %>% dyEvent(date = df_sub$Date[i], label='xyz', labelLoc='bottom')
}
```

> by: user2996185 in  Sep 29 '15 at 7:06
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32837723/6253668
>
> [dynamically add events to dygraph r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905414/dynamically-add-events-to-dygraph-r)