# dynamically add events to dygraph r

Tags: r, object, dygraphs

I have a dataframe with selected dates from a time series that are outliers. I want to dynamically add them to my dygraph as event lines. 
My data looks like this

```
> head(data)
  Group Date
1 g1 2013-08-26
2 g1 2013-08-27
3 g2 2013-08-29
4 g2 2013-12-31
5 g3 2014-01-08

df_sub <- data[data$Group=='g1',]
```

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a group name and created a dygraph with outliers as event lines.

In my eg. for g1, there are two dates with outliers.

Since the basic function looks like this:

```
p <- dygraph(df_sub) %>% dyEvent(date = '2013-08-26', label='xyz', labelLoc='bottom')
```

I want to dynamically pass two dates and get two event lines. As dyEvent only takes one date, is there a way to do this for multiple dates ?

Thanks

Comment: I would like to ban the use of the "dynamically" from SO questions. It is rarely helpful in understanding what is requested. Instead show all the input and the desired output. Similar problems adhere to to the word "complex" which really should only refer to an R storage mode. AND: You should, as always, include all the library() calls you expect to me needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out that you can build dygraph plots like this:

```
p <- dygraph(df_sub)
p <- p %>% dyEvent(x = '2013-08-26', label='xyz', labelLoc='bottom')
```

Then calling p calls the plot. So you can create more event lines using for cycle:

```
p <- dygraph(df_sub)
for (i in 1:dim(df_sub)[1]){
p <- p %>% dyEvent(date = df_sub$Date[i], label='xyz', labelLoc='bottom')
}
```